# Python objects compared to .NET objects

Tags: .net, python

I'm very comfortable with .NET objects and its framework for reference vs value types. How do python objects compare to .NET objects? Specifically, I'm wondering about equality `obj1 == obj2`, hash-ability (i.e. being able to put in a dict), and copying.

For instance, by default in .NET, all objects are reference types and their equality and hash code is determined by their address in memory. Additionally, assigning a variable to an existing object just makes it point to that address in memory, so there is no expensive copying occurring. It seems that this is the same for python, but I'm not entirely sure.

EDITS:

- Equality

  - [`is` checks for referential equality, `==` checks for value equality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/116891) (but what does value equality mean for objects?)

I was able to find some [useful info from the effbot](http://effbot.org/zone/python-objects.htm) written back in 2000:

> ## Objects
>
> All Python objects have this:
>
> - a unique identity (an integer, returned by `id(x)`)
> - a type (returned by `type(x)`)
> - some content You cannot change the identity.
>
> You cannot change the type.
>
> Some objects allow you to change their content (without changing the
>   identity or the type, that is).
>
> Some objects don’t allow you to change their content (more below).
>
> The type is represented by a type object, which knows more about
>   objects of this type (how many bytes of memory they usually occupy,
>   what methods they have, etc).

Comment: For value/reference compare semantics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Comment: Each object has a unique id. `a is b` is equivalent to `id(a) == id(b)`. Equality comparisons default to this when no `__eq__` or `__cmp__` methods are defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Equality](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

:
- An object with no `__cmp__` or `__eq__` method defined <s>will raise an error if you try to compare it</s> inherits its comparisons from the object `object`. This means that doing `a > b` is equivalent to doing `id(a) > id(b)`.

The `is` keyword is also used to see if two variables point to the same object. The `==` operator on the other hand, calls the `__cmp__` or `__eq__` method of the object it is comparing.

#### [Hashability](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

:
- An object is hashable if there is a `__hash__` method defined for it. All of the basic data types (including strings and tuples) have hash functions defined for them. If there is no `__hash__` method defined for a class, that class will inherit it's hash from the object `object`.

#### [Copying](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html)

:
- `copy`, `copy.deepcopy`, and their respective in class methods `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__`. Use `copy` to copy a single object, `deepcopy` to copy a heirarchy of objects. `deepcopy`

Edits made at the suggestion of agf.

Comment: An object with no `__cmp__` or `__eq__` inherits `object`s comparison, which compares by identity. `object`s `__hash__` implementation also uses identity, so objects are hashable by default. `copy.deepcopy` is when you want to copy a hierarchy of objects, not just an object. `copy` does that and is equivalently controllable by `__copy__`. Your answer isn't wrong but it's terribly incomplete and somewhat misleading.

Comment: you're right. I should have checked the docs before posting. will edit when i get near a computer.

Answer (score 1):

In python you can define the `__eq__` method to handle the `==` operator.

The `is` operator checks if one object **is** the same as the other. (or more specifically two variables that reference one or two objects)

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False
>>> c = a
>>> c is a
True
```

Now, this example uses the `list` type, which you can think of as a class which defines an `__eq__` method that compares equality of all its items.

Same for hash, you define a `__hash__` method in your class that returns an integer that would identify your object. This is also available in the basic types that support hashing. See the `hash` function.